# How do I fix "E0349 no operator matches these operands" error?

Tags: c++, hash

In the `prontHashTable()` method, I'm getting an error on the line for `(auto x : hashTable[i])`. What mistake have I made? Originally, I did that for only an array consisting of integers, but now that I am trying to make a sort of database, I'm getting an E0349 error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double fee;
};

class Hash
{
private:

    int tableSize;
    list<Student>* hashTable;

public:
    Hash(int size)
    {
        
        this->tableSize = size;
        hashTable = new list<Student>[tableSize];
    }

    int hashFunction(int key)
    {
        return (key % tableSize);
    }

    void insertItem(int key, Student value)
    {
        int index = hashFunction(key);
        hashTable[index].push_back(value);
    }

    void printHashTable()
    {
        Student i;
        {
            
            for (auto x : hashTable[i])
            {
                cout << "--->" << x;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: `Student i;` should be `int i;` and a for- loop iterating over all buckets. You should have 2 nested loops: one iterating over buckets and another iterating over the elements in a bucket.

Comment: C++ range-based `for(:)` uses begin() and end() internally, your array accessed through a pointer doesn't have those, you have to go for a traditional `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use an iterator-based `range-for` loop with a dynamic array.  `hashtable` is a pointer to a `list[]` array, and a `range-for` loop simply can't get the iterators it needs from a raw pointer to an array.

You will have to use a non-range `for` loop to iterate the array, eg:

```
void printHashTable()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i)
    {
        for (auto &x : hashtable[i])
        {
            cout << "--->" << x;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, use a `std::vector` instead of `new[]` (especially since you are leaking the `hashTable` anyway), then you can use a `range-for` loop to iterate the array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double fee;
};

class Hash
{
private:

    vector<list<Student>> hashTable;

public:
    Hash(int size)
        : hashTable(size)
    {
    }

    int hashFunction(int key)
    {
        return (key % hashTable.size());
    }

    void insertItem(int key, Student value)
    {
        int index = hashFunction(key);
        hashTable[index].push_back(value);
    }

    void printHashTable()
    {
        for (auto &l : hashtable)
        {
            for (auto &x : l)
            {
                cout << "--->" << x;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```